# Jquery code didn't work inside Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This code inside view in MVC4 where `ViewData["Success"]` contains bool value from controller 
and it's excecuted abd JavaScript alert worked correctly but

```
$("h4.alert_success").css('display', 'block').fadeOut(5000);
```

is not shown in the browser 
hint: this code:

```
$("h4.alert_success").css('display', 'block').fadeOut(5000);
```

worked correctly in another position inside the project

```
@if (ViewData["Success"] != null && (bool)ViewData["Success"]==true)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("success");
        $("h4.alert_success").css('display', 'block').fadeOut(5000);
    </script>
}
```

Comment: This is a legit question and shouldn't have been down-voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include jQuery library and add your code inside DOM ready handler `$(document).ready(function() {....})` or shorter form `$(function() {...});`:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        alert("success");
        $("h4.alert_success").css('display', 'block').fadeOut(5000);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to defer execution until the DOM is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    alert("success");
    $("h4.alert_success").css('display', 'block').fadeOut(5000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @user1960951 this error is becouse you dont have the Jquery reference in you page/project. only add this.

Comment: but the same jquery code works inside the same page in another functionality